# How can I use gradle to build my project both with and without our profiling aspects?

Tags: build, aspectj, gradle

We've developed some profiling aspects that we would like to include in a testing build, but not in our production build.  I'm looking for a best-practices way of structuring the build.gradle file and the source directories.

My initial thought was to create a compileJavaAJ task, and a jarAJ task which depends on compileJavaAJ.  compileJavaAJ would look awfully similar to the compileJava defined in the aspectJ plugin, http://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/raw/0.9-upgrade/aspectjPlugin/aspectJ.gradle.  The problem with just applying this plugin is that it completely replaces compileJava (i.e. the one using javac).  I need two build targets - one that uses javac, the other that uses ajc.  I welcome suggestions if there's a better approach though.

Next, I need to decide where to put the aspectJ code.  I don't want to put it in src/main/java, because the java compiler will choke on it.  So, I'm thinking of defining a new SourceSet, src/main/aspectJ, which only compileJavaAJ knows about.  A SourceSet is supposed to model java code though, so I'm not quite sure if this is the correct approach.

Any input is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a property like "withAspectJ" to differentiate between compiling with and without your aspects. Have a look on the following snippet:

```
if(project.hasProperty('withAspectj') && project.getProperty("withAspectj")){
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/aspectj'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This snippets adds the directory src/main/aspectj to your main sourceset if a property named withAspectj evaluates to true. Now you can put all your aspects into this specific directory. If you don't pass the withAspectj property, the replaced compileJava task will compile your code without wiring the aspects into it. 
But if you run your build from the command line:
    gradle build -PwithAspectj=true

all aspects located in src/main/aspectj will be wired into your code.

hope that helped,

regards,

René

Comment: With this approach though, I need to replace the compileJava task with a task that uses ajc.  The build would end up using ajc even when it wasn't compiling aspects.  I ended up creating an aspectJ sourceSet, added all of the java srcDirs to that source set, re-defined the compileAspectJJava task to use ajc, and created a jar task that uses the output from compileAspectJJava.